# Can $\int u dv=uv- \int v du$ be used in complex integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

When I study complex analysis, I meet a problem established by myself. Assume $f(z)$ is an analytic function in a open disc of $D(0,r)$, then $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ both have Taylor series. We set $f(z)=\sum_n a_nz^n$, $f'(z)=\sum_nb_nz^n$. Obviously, we have an equation of
$(n+1)a_{n+1}=b_n$. Now I want to prove the equation by integral, which means I want to prove the following equation,
$$(n+1)\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}dz=\int_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz,$$
where $\gamma$ is a circle around zero with radius of $\epsilon<r$.

Here is the way I prove:

Substitute $\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ for $z$, we have the right side is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f'(\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{\epsilon^{n+1} e^{i(n+1)\theta}} d(\epsilon e^{i\theta})=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1} e^{i(n+1)\theta}}df(\epsilon e^{i\theta})\\=\frac{f(\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{\epsilon^{n+1} e^{i(n+1)\theta}}\big|^{2\pi}_0-\int_0^{2\pi}f(\epsilon e^{i\theta})d\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1} e^{i(n+1)\theta}}\ \ (*)\\=0+(n+1)\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{\epsilon^{n+2} e^{i(n+2)\theta}}d(\epsilon e^{i\theta})=(n+1)\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}}dz.$$

Now it seems the proof is completed, but I am confusing that whether the deduction $(*)$ is correct, which also means, can I use the form $\int u dv=uv- \int v du$ on analytic function?

Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: Sure, integration by parts is just saying that $u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)=\int_C (uv)'(z)dz$ for a curve $C:a\to b$ around which $uv$ is analytic.